# ColdFusion REST service over SSL

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2021

I have REST services running on a ColdFusion 2023 server.  By default, the service responds to requests on port 8500.  I'd like for this to work over SSL and have the REST service respond on port 443 by going to `https://sample-domain.com/rest/my_rest_cfc`.

How is this achieved?

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot use IIS or Apache to deal with it? The connector to these comes as default.

Comment: Agree with @haxtbh although I might go all 2020s and say "Nginx" instead of either of those two ;-) The point remains, though, SSL is usually the job of the web server, not the app server. Additionally I would not use the built-in web server for production purposes. Although the web server Tomcat bundles *is* kinda production ready these days, it's not an industry standard and yer kinda boxing yerself in a bit here.

Comment: Are you using ColdFusion 2023 Enterprise with the built-in service? If so, I believe that you can do this, but all 443 traffic to the web/CF Server would be routed through the dedicated API service. Do you require the built-in services? Have you evaluated the alternatives; Taffy.io or ColdBox? (I use Taffy. It doesn't require an enterprise license.) Not sure which web server you're using, but we've had some luck w/ports by setting up IIS proxies.

Comment: The current infrastructure is Apache and CF2023 Standard.  I went the proxy route in setting up the web server to proxy requests to that domain to port 8500.